# infinispan-rhq-plugin, can't find Infinispan instances

Tags: plugins, infinispan, rhq

Following this info:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Management+Tooling#ManagementTooling-RHQ

Fresh RHQ install. Server OK. Agent OK

Uploaded infinispan-rhq-plugin to the serve. Synced it to the agent ok.

Can't find any  Infinispan instances at " Inventory/Discovery Queue"
What log files or tests can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at the agent log?

Comment: @HeikoRupp I have the same problem here, using the new Infinispan 7,1. Error log on the agent is:    `2015-03-16 15:24:19,001 ERROR [ResourceDiscoveryComponent.invoker.daemon-1] (org.rhq.plugins.jmx.JMXDiscoveryComponent)- Failed to connect to JMX service URL [service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:6996/jmxrmi].
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to JMX service URL [service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:6996/jmxrmi].
 at org.rhq.plugins.jmx.JMXDiscoveryComponent.connect(JMXDiscoveryComponent.java:504).... `

Comment: That documentation is deprecated. Did you check [Infinispan's user guide](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.1.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_rhq)? Also, what Infinispan version are you using?

Comment: See how in the documentation we mention the need to start Infinispan instances with: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6996 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`